# How to format with non-English quotation marks in .NET?

Tags: .net, internationalization

While on holiday in Austria recently, I noticed that quotation marks looked different to the ones I'm used to seeing here in Britain. Checking Wikipedia shows that [things are quite different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks) all around the world.

Given that I already use culture-dependent decimal and list separators in my C# code, I'd like to also use the correct quotation marks. Does anyone know where, if anywhere, I'd find the relevant characters in the .NET framework classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll be the Unicode characters, which are supported out-of-the-box in .NET and most character fonts.

An obscenely detailed discussion is on Wikipedia here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs.

In C#, you'd use e.g. "\u00AB" to define the left-guillemet: « - and so on, based on the table in that article.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, I'd need to use the unicode values in your link PLUS the details in the original question's link to work out which character to use? In other words, there's nothing in .NET (or in Windows' own settings) that will do that mapping for me?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware, no. .NET understands cultural differences for number, currency and dates, but not text. There are non-trivial questions concerning e.g. placement of other punctuation marks and spaces that make this impractical. (For example: '"He was going to say something," we thought' has the comma inside the quotes in British English but wouldn't necessary be the same in French.

Comment: No, there is nothing in .NET for that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, .Net won't give you such information on its own. You need another source.
The one I have in mind is [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), namely [ICU4C](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/index.html) which in fact reads these from [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/).

Anyway, you would need to actually call [ulocdata_getDelimiter](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ulocdata_8h.html#aed210881dffb9872c379b50c54681495) from [ulocdata.h](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ulocdata_8h.html) passing appropriate [ULocaleDataDelimiterType constant](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ulocdata_8h.html#a2de6cb7db4865c46fd28fdd1d31fbfdf), that is the actual quotation mark you are interested in.
Of course first you would need to actually import (at least) one of the DLL's and [instantiate ULocaleData](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ulocdata_8h.html#aea69205230937829cc6c7bea014be082) but it is possible.
I know it is nowhere near as easy as using [TextInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.aspx) (which as we know does not provide such information) but...

Comment: Wow, that's astonishing. This thing even tells you what standard measurement units and paper sizes are available in a locale... I wonder how it copes with British measurements (typically millimetres, until you get in a car, at which point it's miles...)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like an omission in the NLS data. However it's hard to think of an example where you would programmatically construct quoted text in isolation. In practice you would rely on localization to provide whatever text includes quotation marks and for example `'a "string"'` would get translated to `'une «chaîne»'` in French. The quotes are typically a localization issue rather than a culture formatting issue. As such, should you really need to construct quoted text, you could solve the problem by adding the quotes to your string table, assuming your app is getting localized (if you don't localize, it's probably a good thing that the quotes stay as in English).

For example your en-US string (with the quotes delimiting the string omitted for clarity) would be:

> "{0}"

And the fr-FR version would be:

> «{0}»